How to index an ndarray of unknown dimensions
I have a python code that uses a numpy array to store multi-dimensional data. The dimensionality of the array is determined at runtime so I cannot know in advance the exact number of dimensions, which can be from 3 to 6. One thing I know, though, is that when a dimension exists in the array, it has 100 elements. So right now my analysis code looks something like this:
ndim = myarray.ndim
if ndim == 2:
    for p0 in range(100):
        do_something(myarray[:, p0])
if ndim == 3:
    for p0 in range(100):
        for p1 in range(100):
            do_something(myarray[:, p0, p1])
elif ndim == 4:
    for p0 in range(100):
        for p1 in range(100):
            for p2 in range(100):
                do_something(myarray[:, p0, p1, p2])
elif ndim == 5:
    for p0 in range(100):
        for p1 in range(100):
            for p2 in range(100):
                for p3 in range(100):
                    do_something(myarray[:, p0, p1, p2, p3])
elif ndim == 6:
    for p0 in range(100):
        for p1 in range(100):
            for p2 in range(100):
                for p3 in range(100):
                    for p4 in range(100):
                        do_something(myarray[:, p0, p1, p2, p3, p4])

Of course this works, but I find the code not very elegant and very much cluttered. Is there a better way to do this? I am pretty sure there must be a way to index the array without knowing a priori the number of dimensions, but I cannot find the proper function in the numpy documentation.

Part of a good answer really hinges on what you're actually doing in do_something.

One generic solution is to work with np.ndindex, which returns an iterator over all nd indices given a certain shape. In your case you only want to iterate over the non-batch (all except the first) axes. This can be achieved by selecting the corresponding part of the shape tuple. See the following minimal example:
import numpy as np

myarray = np.arange(24).reshape(2, 3, 4)

shape = myarray.shape

def do_something(array):
    print(array)

for idx in np.ndindex(shape[1:]):
    do_something(myarray[(...,) + idx])

Which prints:
[ 0 12]
[ 1 13]
[ 2 14]
[ 3 15]
[ 4 16]
[ 5 17]
[ 6 18]
[ 7 19]
[ 8 20]
[ 9 21]
[10 22]
[11 23]

The code works the same way no matter the dimension of the array.
I hope this helps!

Define a function that expects a 1d array (not enforced here), and returns something (your dosomething appears to return None):
In [60]: def foo(a1d):
    ...:     return sum(a1d)
    ...:     

And a sample 2d array:
In [61]: x = np.arange(24).reshape(3,8)

apply... takes a 1d function, and iterates on all but one axis:
In [62]: np.apply_along_axis(foo, 0, x)
Out[62]: array([24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45])

Without change we can use it on a 3d or 4d array:
In [63]: np.apply_along_axis(foo, 0, x.reshape(3,2,4))
Out[63]: 
array([[24, 27, 30, 33],
       [36, 39, 42, 45]])

In [64]: np.apply_along_axis(foo, 0, x.reshape(3,2,2,2))
Out[64]: 
array([[[24, 27],
        [30, 33]],

       [[36, 39],
        [42, 45]]])

I don't usually like this apply... since it iterates on  all but one dimension.  Where possible in numpy we try to avoid that kind of iteration.  For example we can use np.sum with an axis specification:
In [65]: x.reshape(3,2,2,2).sum(axis=0)
Out[65]: 
array([[[24, 27],
        [30, 33]],

       [[36, 39],
        [42, 45]]])

Still if you must iterate on all-but-one dimension, this apply... is a convenient tool.
